# Geocoding Accuracy

Tags: geocoding

I'm brand new to geocoding and have a relatively large dataset of addresses 100,000+.  When I geocode them using MapMarker Professional I get about 10% that I'm not able to geocode with a high level of precision (I get mostly S2 precision values back which mean that it was able to match to a Primary Postal Code centroid, centerpoint of the Primary Postal Code boundary).  Each of the addresses has already been standardized so they should be valid (I have taken a random sample and run them through the USPS Zip Code Lookup process to verify this).  My question is, should I be able to geocode addresses with a higher degree of accuracy than what I'm seeing or am I expecting too much of the products currently on the market?  I've tried geocoding using google and yahoo's services without any better luck.  All of the services appear to be able to give me the postal code centroid, but none of them appear to have enough information to be able to give me distinct coordinates for houses in at least 98% of the addresses I send to it.

Thanks for any guidance you can provide,
Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding is an imprecise process.  The addresses you are geocoding that don't have good precision are likely in rural areas, where it is not uncommon for addresses to be off by up to a mile.

They only know where addresses are by taking the number at the start and end of a street segment, and dividing from there.